# Divide the vertice set in a graph into $k$ partitions, can the longest path of connected parts in induced subgraphs be bounded?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I have a graph $G=(V,E)$, now I want to divide the vertex set into $K$ partitions, making the number of remaining edges in each induced subgraphs as small as possible. For example, the best case is that all the subgraphs are  independent sets, each with an empty edge set. Given a $G$, can I get a division leading to all independent sets? Or can I get a division that in all induced subgraphs, if there are edges, the longest path of the connected parts are bounded by a value?

The problem looks like a relaxed graph coloring given $K$ colors. The constraint is relaxed from all adjacent vertices are in different colors to no more than $B$ consecutive vertices in a path can be painted the same color. I want to minimize the $B$. Is there any theory for the $B$?

Comment: If all subgraphs have an empty edge set, then doesn't that imply, amongst other things infinite diameter? This question is worded extremely vaguely.

Comment: You say you 'decompose' the graph into subgraphs, but I think you mean you take a partition of the vertices and then consider the induced subgraphs, right?  Or do you partition the edges?

Comment: @Steven Thank you for your questions. I've fixed my expression. Indeed, I take a partition of the vertices and then consider the induced subgraphs.

Comment: In English (unlike, say, Italian), it's one vertex, two vertices; there is no "vertice".

Comment: @Mike Sorry for my vague expression. I mean the diameter of the connected parts, if there is(are) edge(s). I've re-edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning the vertices of a graph $G$ into $K$ independent sets is equivalent to finding a (proper) $K$-coloring of $G$. There is a lot of literature on both algorithmic and theoretical aspects of this problem.

What you are looking for in case such a partition does not exist is still unclear to me. Since it looks like fewer edges is better to you, I guess you want the diameter to be as large as possible in each induced subgraph?
I doubt there will be any literature on this, but I am quite certain that simple graph-coloring algorithms can easily be modified to solve this problem.

Comment: Yep, I've tried to search variants of graph-coloring algorithm. What I want indeed looks like if $K$ colors fail to color the graph, the constraint is relaxed from all adjacent vertices are in different colors to no more than $B$ consecutive vertices in a path can be painted the same color. I want to minimize the $B$.

Comment: If you mean to minimize the longest 'simple path' in each color, then this problem is taken to a new level, because finding the longest path in a graph already is NP-hard.  Unless you really mean 'longest shortest path', which is the diameter (as you mentioned earlier).

Comment: Thank you for bringing it to my attention. I mean to minimize the longest 'simple path' in each color.

Comment: Then I would try something like an optimization algorithm based on backtracking: try all legal K-colorings, keeping track of the shortest possible 'longest path' currently known, and pruning the search whenever a longer path is detected. The place to look for such a path can then be restricted, for it must include at least the last-colored vertex.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have some heuristic ideas for solving it. I thought there were theories providing a bound. But it seems too difficult.